# How do I detect a BitmapImage failing to load?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code to load an image from a url.  If the url doesn't exist, a placeholder should be loaded instead.

```
public BitmapImage Image
{
    get
    {
        if (m_image == null)
        {
            try
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.UriSource = new Uri(m_photoPath);
                image.DecodePixelHeight = s_imagePixelHeight;
                image.EndInit();
                m_image = image;
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException)
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.BeginInit();
                image.UriSource = new Uri(c_placeholderImagePath);
                image.DecodePixelHeight = s_imagePixelHeight;
                image.DecodePixelWidth = s_imagePixelWidth;
                image.EndInit();
                m_image = image;
            }
        }
        return m_image;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the weirdest error - when `m_photoPath` is a url which causes a 404 in any browser, no exception is thrown.  I've tried checking if the file exists by using an `HttpWebRequest`, but everytime I call `[HttpWebRequest instance].GetResponse()`, there's a really, really long timeout (possibly infinite - I haven't waited around to find out).  So `HttpWebRequest` isn't an option.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've suggested an edit that includes adding the WPF tag. I hope that's accurate - please tag it differently otherwise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image fails to download, the BitmapImage's [**DownloadFailed**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadfailed.aspx) event fires. No exception is thrown. You can wire the event up anytime, though it would be pragmatic to do it before calling EndInit!

This couldn't really be handled by an exception, since something could give up on downloading the image at any arbitrary point in the future - there's nowhere really to put a try/catch block.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually discovered that on my own, moments ago, and was coming back to answer myself, but you're exactly right.  I changed to using that handler, and it works great.  And the way I was originally trying to do it was sort of hacky anyway.

Comment: Awesome! \o/ Glad you found it.